# Can't add a JButton to a JPanel while running

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jpanel

I want to add a JButton to a JPanel after a click on a button so here is my code :

```
   JButton testButton = null;

   private void sendmessageButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       testButton = new JButton();       
       totalPane.add(testButton,BorderLayout.CENTER);
       totalPane.revalidate();
       totalPane.repaint();
    }
```

I am using the Netbean GUI builder. When I click, nothing happens. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried, maximize and then restore your windows (after you click on the button)

Comment: You should add a simple output in your method to see if it's called.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `totalPane.add(testButton,BorderLayout.CENTER);` note that only one component can be in the `CENTER` of a `BorderLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is correct for standard [Swing JComponents](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html),

1) is `totalPane` initialized

2) is `totalPane` added to the Container

3) is `totalPane` visible in the Container

4) is there [BorderLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) defined for `totalPane`, othervise is there [FlowLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) by default

you can simply to test it by add [Borders](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) (`totalPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));`) to the `totalPane`

Answer (score 0):

Your code for adding the button is correct, although your call to repaint() wont achieve anything - revalidate() is enough.

My guess is that your sendmessageButtonActionPerformed-method is never invoked. It does not look like any method that is part of ActionListener or any other listener. How have you set up the ActionListener on the button that triggers the add?

Answer (score 0):

Please debug your code and check whether your method is executed. If it isn't, then we know the problem and you must make sure your method is executed.

Note that there is an alternative to your approach, you can create your button at initialize time and set its visibility to false. When you need it you can make it visible. However, your approach should work.